# Deluge won't download anything?

Tags: bittorrent

I have used Deluge for a day now and everything went great, i didn't change anything except made HTTP Auth proxies and encrypting the entire stream, along with adding the addon Extractor and label. After a day of perfect use, it just refuses to download anything. It sends a announce to the tracker (i am downloading Crackstation.net's wordlist right now) and it stops with a error. There isn't a name for the error though, also this isn't just Crackstation's problem, every torrent and magnet i use won't even start to download. How do i fix this problem?

Comment: @Burgi Perhaps I am misunderstanding your comment but the wordlist is "pay what you want [...]Even nothing."  -- https://crackstation.net/buy-crackstation-wordlist-password-cracking-dictionary.htm

Comment: "The list contains every wordlist, dictionary, and password database leak that I could find on the internet (and I spent a LOT of time looking). It also contains every word in the Wikipedia databases (pages-articles, retrieved 2010, all languages) as well as lots of books from Project Gutenberg. It also includes the passwords from some low-profile database breaches that were being sold in the underground years ago. "  Heh. Dosen't look like piracy, and is a legitimate thing to download if you're a security researcher. Despite the name, its cool

Comment: What sort of icon? I know some ISPs mess with torrents so you can't get a connection in, even with encrypted connections, and changing the port helps. Try that. The torrent itself is fine (and pretty darned fast)